# Statically declare interface pointer array to specialized classes

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have an interface `IColumn`. And I implement this interface in specialized classes such as `CTextColumn`, `CIntColumn`, `CLongColumn`, etc.

I need a class to be able to reference these specialized classes in a loop. So I allocate an `IColumn` array, and then allocate each item in that array.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    IColumn** m_pColumns;

    MyClass()
        : m_pColumns(new IColumn* [NUM_COLUMNS])
    {
        m_pColumns[0] = new CTextColumn(...);
        m_pColumns[1] = new CIntColumn(...);
        m_pColumns[2] = new CLongColumn(...);
    }
}
```

But I would like to eliminate this many dynamic allocations (which must all be freed). If I could declare this all statically, I would.

The only way I've thought of to reduce the number of allocations is something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    IColumn** m_pColumns;

    CTextColumn Col1;
    CIntColumn Col2;
    CLongColumn Col3;

    MyClass()
        : m_pColumns(new IColumn* [NUM_COLUMNS])
    {
        m_pColumns[0] = &Col1;
        m_pColumns[1] = &Col2;
        m_pColumns[2] = &Col3;
    }
}
```

I have many classes like this with many columns. This could get a little unwieldy.

Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IColumn>>`.

Comment: @Jarod42: Can you explain how that would reduce the number of allocations?

Comment: Reduce the number of **raw/manual** allocations and so no manual memory management to do (which seems to be one of your issue), but indeed, you still have allocations.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: What do you want to reduce exactly ? Nor the STL nor C++ compiler know about what you want to achieve. I'm afraid you will have to write everything by your hand. Or you may also write some "metadata" parser, where you describe what you want in the metadata and the parser will allocate it for you.

Comment: @Gojita: As indicated, I'm trying to decrease the number of memory allocations and deallocations. That's why I said I'd declare it statically - *if I could*. And that's why I showed one way to reduce *some* of the allocations.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: You can stil get ride of the new ICOlumn*[NUM COLUMS] bu using std::arrray ... don't know if it's of any interest for you

Comment: @Gojita: How would that help? Doesn't that allocate memory at runtime?

Comment: I think there is a generational gap here. I started by programming assembly language, and it just seems like the newer developers don't even think about stuff like that. Yeah, STL is great. It makes it easier to program stuff. But as developers, you should still think about efficiency. If I need to allocate all these blocks of memory, I can. But I've been away from C++ for a while and just wanted to see if maybe I was missing some cool techniques.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: There's also another solution, but it will require a lot of work. It's to write your own "memory allocator" by using preallocation of big memory block. You allocate once a huge (depending on your needs) memory block and then use "in place new allocator". The memory is allocate once and only once. YOu will then create your COlumn object inside this block. But the "Where" is up to you. As I said, it will be a lot of work. Don't know if it's suitable for you

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

This is for polymorphic behavior and when you don't know the number of elements a priori:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct IColumn {
  virtual int foo() { return 0; }
};
struct CTextColumn: public IColumn {
  int foo() { return 1; }
};
struct CIntColumn: public IColumn {
  int foo() { return 2; }
};
struct CLongColumn: public IColumn {
  int foo() { return 3; }
};

struct MyClass
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IColumn>> m_pColumns;

  MyClass()
  : m_pColumns(3)
  {
      m_pColumns[0] = std::make_unique<CTextColumn>();
      m_pColumns[1] = std::make_unique<CIntColumn>();
      m_pColumns[2] = std::make_unique<CLongColumn>();
  }
};

int main()
{
  MyClass mc;
  std::cout << mc.m_pColumns[0]->foo() << mc.m_pColumns[1]->foo() << mc.m_pColumns[2]->foo();
}
```

Edit:

When you know the amount of each kind of element a priori you can use a `std::array` for each.

> `std::array` is a container that encapsulates fixed size arrays.

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

So everything is static and *structors are called normally.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <array>

#define NUMBER_OF_CTextColumn 6
#define NUMBER_OF_CIntColumn 7
#define NUMBER_OF_CLongColumn 8

struct IColumn {
  virtual int foo() { return 0; }
};
struct CTextColumn: public IColumn {
  int foo() { return 1; }
};
struct CIntColumn: public IColumn {
  int foo() { return 2; }
};
struct CLongColumn: public IColumn {
  int foo() { return 3; }
};

struct MyClass
{
  std::array<CTextColumn, NUMBER_OF_CTextColumn> m_pCTextColumns;
  std::array<CIntColumn, NUMBER_OF_CIntColumn> m_pCIntColumns;
  std::array<CLongColumn, NUMBER_OF_CLongColumn> m_pCLongColumns;
};

int main()
{
  MyClass mc;
  std::cout << mc.m_pCLongColumns[0].foo() << mc.m_pCIntColumns[1].foo() 
    << mc.m_pCTextColumns[2].foo();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not reduce the number of memory allocations and deallocations.

Comment: Why do you want it? Do you know a priori how much of each kind of columns you have on your data?

Comment: I want it because allocating one block of memory is more efficient than allocating a hundred blocks of memory. I can know the number and type of columns beforehand.

Comment: @JonathanWood please check if this enlightens the matter

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of allocation inside `MyClass`, you might do:

```cpp
class MyClass
{
public:
    std::array<IColumn*, 3u> m_pColumns;

    CTextColumn Col1;
    CIntColumn Col2;
    CLongColumn Col3;

    MyClass() : m_pColumns{{&Col1, &Col2, &Col3}}
    {
    }
};
```

Or use `std::tuple`

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    std::tuple<CTextColumn, CIntColumn, CLongColumn> m_Columns;
};
```

And

```cpp
std::apply([](auto&... cols){ (f(cols), ...); }, m_Columns);

auto columns = std::apply([](auto&... cols){
                              return std::array<IColumn*, sizeof...(cols)>{{cols...}};
                          },
                          m_Columns);
```

Comment: Doesn't `std::array` need to dynamically allocate the memory in this case?

Comment: `std::array<T, N> a;` is mostly equivalent to `T a[N];`. No dynamic memory allocation.